# How to access a custom html element used in different .ts file from another component?

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I want to access and manipulate a custom html element which is declared in another .ts file of my project from a component.

`/src/app/@theme/layouts/one-column/one-column-layout.ts` this is the file where the custom html element is used.

`/src/app/pages/dashboard/dashboard.component.ts` this is from where I want to access that custom element and append some innerHTML in it.

I've almost checked everything but didn't get any satisfactory answer; what I've already checked:

1. [How to access method from .ts file into html file in angular2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43451569/how-to-access-method-from-ts-file-into-html-file-in-angular2)
2. [How to access one component's state from another component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36837958/how-to-access-one-components-state-from-another-component)
3. [How to append HTML element from ts file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57330615/how-to-append-html-element-from-ts-file)
4. [AngularJS 2 how to access DOM element within TS file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41194687/angularjs-2-how-to-access-dom-element-within-ts-file)
5. [Angular access html content via .ts file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51011526/angular-access-html-content-via-ts-file)

In `one-column-layout.ts` I want to append HTML in `<ng-content></ng-content>`

```
@Component({
  selector: 'ngx-one-column-layout',
  styleUrls: ['./one-column.layout.scss'],
  template: `
      <nb-sidebar responsive right>
        <nb-tabset>
          <nb-tab tabIcon="person-outline" tabTitle="Customers">
            <ng-content tag="right-sidebar"></ng-content>
          </nb-tab>
        </nb-tabset>
      </nb-sidebar>
  `,
})
```

I expect to append my html to this custom element, I know this is a rookie question though.

Comment: Hey dude. I would urge you to go the direction of a viewchild (but read elementref - which you can make publicly available on the component). Also try not to inject html into the ng-content element - I don't even think it exists at runtime. That is used to 'pass' markup into your component from outside. Rather make your own viewchild to inject into

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wanna access one component from another, first of all, you should separate the template from the .ts file. Then you can use @ViewChild and send it to the other component with @Input / @Output depending the direction.